# Add sources to build php extension

Tags: php, c, build, php-extension, m4

I want to write a test php extension, which will provide a test class. I want to extract class declaration into a separate C-File and call class registration from module init function of myext.c file. I have the following files:

```
   testlib/
    test_class.c
   myext.c
   php_myext.h
   config.m4
   ...
```

Now config.m4 file is quite simple:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(myext, [whether to enable myext support], [  --enable-myext           Enable myext support])

if test "$PHP_MYEXT" != "no"; then
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(myext, myext.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

How to configure config.m4 to be able to add test_class.c to extension building?

### UPDATE:

How to configure config.m4 to make it searching .c files in a specific folder and add to extension building automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(myext, myext.c testlib/test_class.c, $ext_shared)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more question: how to automate it? I mean how to make script, which will look through some folder and add .c files to the extension automatically?